# JSF 2.0 - Best way to access data across beans?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSF 2.0 app that runs on multiple domains and serves up different content based on the domain running.
I have a table in the database that contains the domain names, along with an id.
I have a header and footer bean and want to be able to access the domain id in both these beans, but I only want to retrieve the domain id once.
Should I create a common bean? If so, how do I ensure this bean is executed when the session starts?
How do I access the domain id in the common bean from the header and footer bean?

Comment: what are header and footer beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your common bean as `@SessionScoped` bean and use an instance of it in other beans.